# How to extract an id from id field in html to send it via axios in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've no idea how to get the id of element in order to send it. I use Vue 2.

** offers array i get from the API, so it is just an example.

I need getting id dynamically in order to send a comment for the exact offer.

Maybe it is the wrong way to do it, but it would be great if it worked this way

HTML:

```
<div v-for="offer in offers">
        <p> {{ offer.description }}</p>

      <div class="form-group col-md-9">
        <b-form-textarea :id="`${offer.id}`" placeholder="Comment!" rows="1" v-model="text"></b-form-textarea>
        <button @click="createComment()" class="button btn btn-success">Send!</button>
      </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
data () {
      return {
          offers: [
    {id: 1,
     description: "some"
    },
    {id: 2,
     description: "another"
    },
],
        }
    },


        methods: { 
  createComment() {
     const FormData = { 
      text: this.text,
      offer_related:   NEED TO GET THE VALUE OF TEXTAREA :id here
    } 
    // axios
    // .post(`/api/v1/comments/`, FormData)
  },
```

Comment: just add an argument to your `createComment` method, make it `createComment(id) { ... }`, and use the click handler like this `@click="createComment(offer.id)"`.

Comment: thank you! it works, but now it fills two text areas simultaneously. Bet it's because of v-model. Can I change it somehow?

Comment: add another property to your data `text: {},`, and use `v-model="text[offer.id]"`, and access text values with `text[offer.id]`.

Comment: No idea why you deleted your last question... Have a look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/uhfdpj43/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great thanks to @don_aman!

The final code will look like:

```
<div v-for="offer in offers">
        <p> {{ offer.description }}</p>

      <div class="form-group col-md-9">
        <b-form-textarea :id="`${offer.id}`" placeholder="Comment!" rows="1" v-model="text[offer.id]"></b-form-textarea>
        <button @click="createComment(`${offer.id}`)" class="button btn btn-success">Send!</button>
      </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
data () {
      return {
          offers: [
    {id: 1,
     description: "some"
    },
    {id: 2,
     description: "another"
    },
],
     text: {},
        }
    },


        methods: { 
  createComment(id) {
     const FormData = { 
      text: this.text[id],
      offer_related:id,
    } 
    axios
    .post(`/api/v1/comments/`, FormData)
  },
```

Comment: A quick noitce, you can do this ```@click="createComment(offer.id})"``` instead of ```@click="createComment(`${offer.id}`)```, same with ```:id="`${offer.id}`"```